# How do I select few years from a dataset consisting of several years

Tags: r

I have a dataset consisting of daily values for about 20 years. I have to select only few years from it, say like 10 years. My dataset consists of data from `1996` to `2013`. I need to create a file that has only 10 years from `2004` to `2013`.

However, I am familiar with the use of grep command to select one particular year.

```
Df <- Df[grep("2013", Df$Year), ]
```

Is it possible to choose several years at the same time.

I tried doing

```
Df[grep(c("2004", "2005", "2006"), Df$Year), ]
```

but this does not work.

Comment: If you want to match exact values, `grep` isn't usually the best solution. It is safer to use operators such as `==` or `%in%` because `grep` can return unexpected results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya, Just put those last digits inside a character class.

```
Df <- Df[grep("201[345]", Df$Year), ]
```

This would select the rows in which it has `2013`, `2014`, `2015` numbers present on `Year` column.

> I need to create a file that has only 10 years from 2004 to 2013.

```
Df <- Df[grep("20(0[4-9]|1[0-3])", Df$Year), ]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nU5lH3/1)

Comment: Thanks. I hope this works for selecting `2013`, `2014` and `2015`. But what about `2004-2013`.

Comment: I learned all the stuffs from this site only.. ie, seeing and understanding the elder's answers and I ask them directly if there any doubts. Maybe you should consider seeing this http://www.regular-expressions.info/ site..

Comment: @AvinashRaj I need a help in selecting months. `1` `11` `12`. can i use similar method to do that?

Comment: @ShretaGhimire ya, `Df[grep("^1[12]?$", Df$month), ] `

Comment: It makes the subset of months `11` and `12` but doesn't include `1`. @AvinashRaj

Comment: better if you ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could help:

```
Df <- Df[(as.numeric(Df$Year) >= 2004) & (as.numeric(Df$Year) <= 2013),]
```

or in a more compact form, as suggested by @DavidArenburg:

```
Df <- Df[as.numeric(Df$Year) %in% 2004:2013, ]
```

Comment: Or just `Df[as.numeric(Df$Year) %in% 2004:2013, ]` maybe

Comment: I like that, @DavidArenburg . In the end, unless performance is key, I think that what usually matters most is legibility, and this is to a large extent subjective. Ideally one should understand the code as quickly as possible looking at it, say, one year later.

Comment: I could agree, though this looks as intuitive to me :) You can add this to your answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Why uses grep when you can use subset or any other option?

```
subset(DF, Year >= 2004 & Year <= 2013)
```

Or filter from dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% filter(Year >= 2004 & Year <= 2013)
```

or data.table in case you are using this package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[Year >= 2004 & Year <= 2013]
```